# Polymorphic dot product in Scala and anonymous function shorthand

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, anonymous-function

I'd like to implement a "matrix dot product" in Scala in the following way:

```
type Real = Double
type Row = Array[Real]
type Matrix = Array[Row]

def dot[T](f: (T,T) => Real)(as: Iterable[T], bs: Iterable[T]): Real =
  (for ((a, b) <- as zip bs) yield f(a, b)) sum

def rowDot(r1: Row, r2: Row) = dot(_*_)(r1, r2)
def matDot(m1: Matrix, m2: Matrix) = dot(rowDot)(m1, m2)
```

However, the definition of rowDot doesn't work.  Scala needs explicit type annotations for the anonymous function `(_*_)`, so instead I must write

```
def rowDot(r1: Row, r2: Row) = dot((x:Real, y: Real) => x*y)(r1, r2)
```

or

```
def rowDot = dot((x:Real, y: Real) => x*y) _
```

Is there some way to change the definition of dot so that the shorthand `(_*_)` can be used?

Edit: Another confusion: matDot also gives type errors in certain circumstances.  It fails with Arrays of Arrays, but not with Lists of Arrays

```
scala> matDot(Array(Array(1.0,2.0)), Array(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)))
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Array[Double]]
 required: Iterable[Iterable[Real]]
              matDot(Array(Array(1.0,2.0)), Array(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)))
                          ^

scala> matDot(List(Array(1.0,2.0)), List(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0)))
res135: Real = 5.0
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Just a warning: there is lots and lots of boxing and unboxing in the code you wrote.  It will work, but it won't be fast.

Comment: Good to know.  Can you point me in the right direction for improving it?  In code that uses this, I'm exploiting the behavior of zip with lists of different lengths in an important way, so I'd rather not simply use some dedicated linear algebra library.

Comment: There is no good direction, unfortunately.  Scala's libraries are designed for maximal expressive power, not maximal computational efficiency, when there is a tradeoff between those two goals.  You can look at Scalala for a native Scala linear algebra package, or various Java packages (benchmarked at http://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/wiki/RuntimeQ9400_2010_02) with a wrapper that you provide that also implements features you need (e.g. zip).  If performance of the matrix operations will not be critical, however, you may not need to worry.

Comment: I've just seen (and tried to answer) your EDIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

specifying `dot[Real]` explicitly should work too.

```
def rowDot(r1: Row, r2: Row) = dot[Real](_*_)(r1, r2)
```

**EDIT**

replying to your edit: I think the issue is that the implicit conversion from `Array` to `WrappedArray` is not applied recursively when you have a `Array[Array]`.

`Array[Int]` is not an `Iterable[Int]`; normally, when you assign it to a Iterable, an `Array[Int]` is implicitly converted to a `WrappedArray[Int]` (where `WrappedArray` **is** a Iterable[Int]). This is what happens when you use `List[Array[Int]]` (you get a `List[WrappedArray[Int]]` implicitly).

However, as I said, the implicit conversion is not applied recursively, so an `Array[Array[Int]]` is not implicitly converted to `WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Int]]`.

Here's a REPL session that demonstrates the problem:

A List[Array[Int]] can be assigned to Iterable[Iterable[Int]] (note that Array is converted to WrappedArray)

```
scala> val i : Iterable[Iterable[Int]] = List(Array(1,2), Array(1,2,3))
i: Iterable[Iterable[Int]] = List(WrappedArray(1, 2), WrappedArray(1, 2, 3))
```

An Array[Array[Int]] does not work automatically (as you discovered)

```
scala> val j : Iterable[Iterable[Int]] = Array(Array(1,2), Array(1,2,3))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Array[Int]]
 required: Iterable[Iterable[Int]]
       val j : Iterable[Iterable[Int]] = Array(Array(1,2), Array(1,2,3))
                                              ^
```

However, with some hand-holding (converting manually the inner Arrays to WrappedArrays) everything works again:

```
    scala> import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
    import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

    scala> val k : Iterable[Iterable[Int]] = Array(WrappedArray.make(Array(1,2)),
 WrappedArray.make(Array(1,2,3)))
    k: Iterable[Iterable[Int]] = WrappedArray(WrappedArray(1, 2), WrappedArray(1, 2,
     3))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and also the clarification about Array's and Iterable's.  The fact that Array isn't iterable seems odd -- is this a necessary consequence of representing arrays as Java arrays?

Comment: yes, it's for interoperability with java. Scala has kept java types and implicitly converts them to their scala richer counterparts (see also string for another example)

Answer (score 3):

Yes - if you switch your argument lists around. Type inference on function parameters works more effectively when the function parameter is alone in the last argument list:

```
def dot[T](as: Iterable[T], bs: Iterable[T])(f: (T,T) => Real): Real =
  (for ((a, b) <- as zip bs) yield f(a, b)) sum

def rowDot(r1: Row, r2: Row) = dot(r1, r2)(_*_)
```